C# english word stemming and lemmatizing using Catalyst - how to do that
I added Catalyst nuget package to my C# project, to help me lemmatize english words. However its documentation is not clear, and lacks of examples, I tried to lemmatize/stem only one word:
Catalyst.Models.English.Register();

Storage.Current = new DiskStorage("catalyst-models");
var nlp = Pipeline.For(Language.English);

var doc = new Document("described", Language.English);
Console.WriteLine(doc.Value); // outputs "described", expected "describe"

But it does nothing for me, with any words I added to it - returned the same value.
Is it capable of lemmatize one word? How? If not - how to do so in C#? In Python using nltk I can do it, but now I need to do so in C#!

Your code does not use nlp at all, probably you forgot to call nlp.ProcessSingle(doc)?
